# how to retrieve the text within the label tag using python selenium ? i want to use this text to assert testcase to pass/fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have used the below print statements and `get_attribute` with value or text returns none. print statement with `.text` returns nothing.

```
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lblSuccessMessage']").get_attribute("value"))
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lblSuccessMessage']").text)

<strong>
    <label id="SuccessMessagelabel">Text message goes here.</label>
</strong>
```

Answer (score 2):

The id is `SuccessMessagelabel`, not `lblSuccessMessage`

```
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='SuccessMessagelabel']").text)
# or
print (driver.find_element_by_id("SuccessMessagelabel").text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. My bad, typo in my statements.I tried - print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='SuccessMessagelabel']").get_attribute("value"))
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='SuccessMessagelabel']").text)